# Swipe row dosent work in react native flatlist

Tags: react-native

I am using a  SwipeRow from 'react-native-swipe-list-view' but when i try to swipe it dose not do anything.I tried to implement it in this way.Tried to call the swipe row function outside the flatlist but doesn't work either. Both method does not work can any one help me.This is the [documentation](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view) of the library.

```
 <FlatList
            data={this.state.data.slice(0, 5)}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={6}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <SwipeRow
                leftOpenValue={75}
                rightOpenValue={-75}>
                <View >
                  <Text >Left</Text>
                  <Text>Right</Text>
                </View>
                <CardItem
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                    paddingRight: 5,
                    paddingBottom: 0,
                    backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor
                  }}>
                  <Left>
                    <Body>
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.props.navigation.navigate('NewsPage', {
                            newsData: (this.state.data),
                            url: (item.news_page_url),
                            title: (item.news_title),
                            news: (item.mobile_news_summary),
                            image: (item.image_url),
                            index: (index),
                            id: item.id,
                            newsImage: (item.news_image),
                            //related_news : (item.related_news)
                          });
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text
                          numberOfLines={3}
                          style={{
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: "700",
                            color: this.state.component ? 'white' : '#343434',
                            fontFamily: 'sans-serif-light'
                          }}>
                          {item.news_title}
                        </Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>

                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: '#B6B6B4',
                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                        }}>
                        {item.news_provider}
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: '#B6B6B4',
                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                        }}>
                        {item.news_datetime}
                      </Text>
                    </Body>
                  </Left>
                </CardItem>
              </SwipeRow>
            )}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this.handleLoadLess}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

They said row that is generally used in a SwipeListView so it's not work if u don't wrap all of them in SwipeListView